# Using query to determine relationship between tables

Tags: sql, relational-database

I am wondering if there is a way to determine the parent - child relationship between tables by looking a query.

```
select...
from table1
where
oid in (
select oid from table2
where mid = ? and  goid = ? and table1_number = ? )
union
select 0 , oid from table2 where mid=? and  goid=? and is_default=\'Y\'
) order by priority desc ';
```

Would I also be able to figure out if it's a 1 -> many 1 -> 1 or many to many?

Comment: I don't think the question is very clear, extending it a bit will probably be good

Comment: I'm using sql. Thanks Bohemian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All databases have a [*catalog*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_catalog), which is a series of system-controlled tables that stores meta-data - data *about* the data.

You haven't said which database you are using, and each has its own way to doing it, but one of those tables will have data about the foriegn-key constraints in your database. You can query that table, joining with other catalog tables as you need, to get what you need.